# Is there a jQuery function to check wether a URL posts to another host?

Tags: jquery, url, target, host

Is there a nice and fancy way to check wether the URL of a link which has been clicked points to another host?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[target="_blank"]').click(function() {
        if (confirm('This link will open in an new window.')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I can not rely on the CMS to filter every link pointing to another host and adding the attribute `target="_blank"`. So i'd like to test the URL of the clicked link which I think is a more robust test.

I know i could write some custom code which would test the various `string starts with` scenarios. But is there already a nice jQuery (or something else) function for this?

**Solution:**

Thanks for your help! I applied this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if (this.host != location.host) {
            $(this).attr('target', '_blank'); // add or override the attribute (in case there isn't one already)
            return confirm('This link will open in an new window.');
        }
    });
});
```

btw: i will use this code only when the site is in mobile mode (using modernizr). So i can wrap the application with `PhoneGap` and prevent that the user will be left in full-screen mode on some random site without being able to go back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compare `location.host` with the Anchor element's `host`.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if (this.host != location.host && confirm('This link will open in an new window.')) {
    $(this).attr('target', "_blank");
  }
  // don't need else, let it be the default behavior of anchor
  // if you don't want to jump to the new page, then add else return false
});
```

Comment: window.open is bad news, likely to be blocked by popup blockers. How about just "return this.host == location.host || confirm('This link will open in a new window.')" (Assuming the link already has target='_blank')

Comment: @darkporter Yep, you are right. But the op said there is no `target='_blank'` now.

Comment: That's not quite it, you still need to return false if the user's like "oh damn, I don't want to leave this site. this site is the best thing  EVAR"

Comment: @darkporter Ok, add it in the comment.

Comment: thanks! i used your solution with if (this.host != location.host)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `host` property of the link to see if it matches the current website's host.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if (this.host != window.location.host) {
     // do something like
     $(this).attr('target', "_blank");
  } else {
     // do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you just want `this.host`

Comment: +1 for covering the case where there's a full absolute link to the domain you're already on.

Answer (score 0):

See live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vevhJ/)

Normally external link would start with `http://`  so try this

```
 $('a[href^="http://"],a[href^="https://"]').on('click', function(){
     if (confirm('This link will open in an new window.')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

});
```

Comment: not always... depends on the way the CMS works... also, what about `https` ?

Comment: Be careful with the "Starts with" selectors as they are considered less performant.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a click handler to *every* link on the page:

```
jQuery('a').click(function() {
  if (this.href.indexOf('http://') == 0) {
    return confirm('Leaving, OK?');
  }
});
```

But that's adding event handlers to a lot of elements and might be inefficient.

The more efficient way would be to add a click handler right to the document. Clicks on A tags bubble up and you could catch them all in one fell swoop. Like:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'A') {
    if (e.target.href.indexOf('http://') == 0) {
      return confirm('Leaving, OK?');
    }
});
```

And for your actual "is external" check, you'd want "http://" or "https://" of course.

**Edit:**

I think I like @hsalama's answer better. Though I'd change it to:

```
jQuery('a[href^="http://"]').add('a[href^="https://"]').click(function() {
  return confirm('This link will open in an new window.');
});
```

And by the way, doing the:

```
if (condition) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Will just get you made fun of by other programmers. Just:

```
return condition;
```